# Doing Backup of database

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, restore

i need to backup my database. Initially in my "Create Backup" page, i have my original database shown. When i click the add new backup button, a new backup of my database has to be created on checking a condition that whether any new changes have been made. If any changes have been made, new backup has to created. Otherwise just an alert msg can be shown that no changes from the last backup file. Can anyone help on this

Comment: It's not clear. What you want ? What you did ? What is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method. Create a new copy of your database and save with a  different name.

```
- (void)copyDatabaseToCache
{
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString *dbPath1 = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newDatabaseName.sqlite"];
    NSString *backupDbPath = @"You should give back up db path here";
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:backupDbPath error:&error];
   NSLog(@"Persistent store size: %@ bytes", [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]);
    if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath1]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:backupDbPath toPath:dbPath1 error:nil];
        }


}
```

Comment: if database already exist  at that path with that same name it will not copy the database. But if you want to replace the old file by new one. Just remove the if condition.

Comment: yeah ok.. But i want to check either the size or modification date of the last backup and want to create a new backup only if there is size difference(i.e., if a change has been made to the last backup).. How can i do that..

Comment: Check i have edited my code. Using NSFileSize you can calculate size of two sqlite. and then compare them and put if consition.

Comment: The code creates a copy of my database.. But instead of renaming the new database with the specified name, it creates a folder with the name and copies my database into it.. and also it keeps on going.. that is, the folder and database copy is again created inside the folder and again the same set is created inside the folder(i.e.., nesting of the folder and databse copy happens).. How can i fix this divyu..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31622/discussion-between-manoj-ellappan-and-divyu)